# Ansible 2.10 on MacOS with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, macos, ansible, homebrew

What's correct way to install Ansible on MacOS? I'v tried a few ways and none works:

- brew has only 2.9
- installing Python 3 via brew or asdf and using pip to install Ansible - Ansible is not on the path, nor in Lib folder

Edit: I've noticed an error, when tryig to manually run ansible script:

```
 /usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Looking at the script it tries to use:

```
#!/usr/local/opt/python@3.9/bin/python3.9
```

which doesn't seem too be a correct path on MacOS

Answer (score 1):

For me I installed first ansible via brew

```
brew install ansible
```

Here the version installed:

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.9.13
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
```

After I install it using pip

```
pip3 install ansible
```

It gives me later:

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.10.2
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
```

Comment: Thank you, but you still uses builtin outdated Python 2.7

Comment: I installed the latest python 3.9 and did the ansible installation via brew and next pip3, did worked for me.

Comment: ah ok, I don't know why it didn't work for me. As for now I've manually linked a few bits and filled $PATH. I hope new ansible version will appear in brew soon